# Dynamic Time Warping Prior to Calculating Correlation Between Two Signals

Tags: time-series, correlation, dynamic-time-warping

I'm trying to find a good way to look at the correlation between signals for a system that has variable resonance time. It seems like Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) might be a good option. I saw a classic example where someone took two sine waves (with random Gaussian noise) offset by some phase and used DTW to align the signals. This looks all well and good.

I then tried taking two randomly generated signals and aligned them according to DTW path. The correlation came out surprisingly high (see below). This would seem to imply that DTW created artifical correlation. Maybe it doesn't make sense to calculate the correlation after DTW because you are potentially compressing or dilating a signal and they are no longer on the same temporal scale. Is it reasonable to align the signals using DTW prior to calculating the correlation? I would appreciate any thoughts on this. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tslearn.metrics import dtw_path

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.rand(100)

np.random.seed(12342)
y = np.random.rand(100)

corr1 = np.corrcoef(x, y)
print(f'Correlation before DTW: {corr1[0, 1]:.4f}')

temp, _ = dtw_path(x, y)
x_path, y_path = zip(*temp)
x_path = np.asarray(x_path)
y_path = np.asarray(y_path)
x_warped = x[x_path]
y_warped = y[y_path]

corr2 = np.corrcoef(x_warped, y_warped)
print(f'Correlation after DTW: {corr2[0, 1]:.4f}')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax[0].plot(x)
ax[0].plot(y)
ax[0].grid(True)
ax[1].plot(x_warped)
ax[1].plot(y_warped)
ax[1].grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Correlation before DTW: 0.0500

Correlation after DTW: 0.8789

[image]